# Google play локали и Bundle

Tags: android, google-play, locale

Допустим приложение поддерживает только **ru** язык.

В Play Console я могу настроить доступность по странам, но не языкам. Я до конца не понимаю как это работает поэтому задаю эти вопросы:

1. Что если я хочу открыть приложение только для тех кто говорит на **ru**, то по каким параметрам google play определяет язык пользователя?(я думаю по языку при регистрации либо языку телефона)
2. Если следуя первому вопросу, имея только **ru** локаль, я должен открыть доступ только для России, то как быть всем остальным кто вне России, но использует ru локаль - получается что для них приложение будет недоступно. А если не закрывать, то те кто не говорит на **ru** могут случайно(в  моих мечтах конечно) скачать приложение и удалить не поняв его языка.
3. Я хочу дать пользователю возможность выбора языка(предположи что оно поддерживает несколько языков). Но я собираю приложение в **[Bundle](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/)**, что означает что юзер получит приложение только с одной локалью(речь об интерфейсе, Bundle соберет apk только с одним языком ), как мне тогда докачать другую локаль?

Три вопроса, но все по теме.

Comment: если у вас в приложении только 1 локаль, то оно не будет рекомандеовтаь ребятам без такой локали. Вот, например, не имея китайского или корейског ов раскладке - никогда не увидите приложения на корейском языке. Думаю, лучше защитой будет название на килилице.

Comment: @Георгий Чеботарев, то есть по раскладке, это удобно. А что с 3-им делать?

Comment: если бы я знал все три ответа, то оформил бы как ответ, а не как комментарий =)

Comment: @ГеоргийЧеботарев, как я понял оно автоматически докачает локаль, если юзер изменит ее на своем устройстве. А учитывая предыдущие ответы - нет необходимости создавать возможность выбора языка. Можешь создать ответ с этой ссылкой https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/195700/what-about-android-app-bundles-language-support